# BLAS : Matrix product in C?

Tags: c, performance, matrix, product, blas

I would like to realize some fast operations in C language thanks to BLAS (no chance to choose another library, it is the only one available in my project).
I do the following operations:

- Invert a square matrix,
- Make a matrix product A*B where A is the computed inverse matrix and B a vector,
- Sum two (very long) vectors.

I heard this kind of operations were possible with BLAS and were very fast. But I searched and found nothing (in C code lines, I mean) which could make me understand and apply it.

Comment: BLAS doesn't include any matrix inversion routines. But what exactly is it you are asking? I don't see an answerable question anywhere.

Comment: Hello talonmies. Sorry if I don't express myself well, I'm French. Anyway, the most important thing is the second operation : make the matrix product with BLAS in C, and I don't find anywhere how to do that.

Comment: I am *very* surprised you haven't been able to find anything. When I search for "C BLAS" with google, I get a number of very useful links for documentation to C BLAS interfaces from Netlib, the GNU scientific library and Intel. Which BLAS library are you using?

Answer (score 5):

The BLAS library was written originally in Fortran. The interface to C is called CBLAS and has all functions prefixed by `cblas_`.

Unfortunately with BLAS you can only address directly the last two points:

- `sgemv` (single precision) or `dgemv` (double precision) performs matrix-vector multiplication
- `saxpy` (single precision) or `daxpy` (double precision) performs general vector-vector addition

BLAS does not deal with the more complex operation of inverting the matrix. For that there is the LAPACK library that builds on BLAS and provides linear algebra opertaions. General matrix inversion in LAPACK is done with `sgetri` (single precision) or `dgetri` (double precision), but there are other inversion routines that handle specific cases like symmetric matrices. If you are inverting the matrix only to multiply it later by a vector, that is essentially solving a system of linear equations and for that there are `sgesv` (single precision) and `dgesv` (double precision).

You can invert a matrix using BLAS operations only by essentially (re-)implementing one of the LAPACK routines.

Refer to one of the many BLAS/LAPACK implmentations for more details and examples, e.g. [Intel MKL](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/index.htm) or [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/faq.html#doc).

Comment: Thanks for your help.
There is a problem : I must compile my work on a server which only knows '-lblas', not '-lcblas'. I found some equivalents (BLAS_dgemv for example, not cblas_dgemv). I made an #include<blas.h>, but server can't find it nowhere. Any help ? Did I forget anything ?
I can find information on cblas_, but very less on blas_...

Comment: Do a search for `*blas*.h` in `/usr/include` if BLAS was installed as a system wide library. It could be that only the runtime library is present without the development headers.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to compute the full inverse? This is very rarely needed, very expensive, and error prone.

It is much more common to compute the inverse multiplied by a vector or matrix. This is very common, fairly cheap, and not error prone. You do not need to compute the inverse to multiply it by a vector.

If you want to compute Z = X^-1Y then you should look at the [LAPACK driver routines](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node26.html). Usually Y in this case has only a few columns. If you really need to see all of X^-1 then you can set Y to be the full identity.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can do what you are asking, but normally it is more stable to do:

- triangular factorization, eg LU factorization, or Cholesky factorization
- use a triangular solver on the factorized matrix

BLAS is quite capable of doing this.  Technically, it's in 'LAPACK', but most/many BLAS implementations include LAPACK, eg OpenBLAS and Intel's MKL both do.

- the function to do the LU factorization is `dgetrf` ("(d)ouble, (ge)neral matrix, (tr)iangular (f)actorization") http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgetrf.f
- then the solver is `dtrsm` ("(d)ouble (tr)iangular (s)olve (m)atrix") http://www.netlib.org/blas/dtrsm.f

Note that to call these from C, note that:

- the function names should be in lowercase, with `_` postfixed, ie `dgetrf_` and `dtrsm_`
- all the parameters should be pointers, eg `int *m` and `double *a`